# never ending Windows phone 8 background agent

Tags: windows-phone-8, background-agents, background-agent

i Know how to create a background agent and how it invokes its onInvoke method.

now is there any way i can create a background thread in the onInvoke method and do a long running task for 1-2 day?

Please the question is not why would i need this,the question is weather it can be done or not.

i don't want the agent to be scheduled for every 30 min,rather on its first invoke,it should start a background thread and do work unless its stopped by app logic.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a Background Agent exceeding 10 min.

Periodic Agent: 25 seconds

Resource-intensive Agent: 10 minutes

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_ConstraintsforPeriodicAgents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_ConstraintsforPeriodicAgents)

Comment: One thing to note is that Resource-intensive agents run in such rare cases, that they are not reliable. They might help in some cases, but the app should work just fine without them.

Comment: ok so if i start abackground agent at my app launch,and then do a photo upload service with resource intensive task ,will it continue as long as i dont kill itself?

i saw photo upload service and audio service dont get terminated,just clearing my concept.